# Android - How to use the same USB device with two apps running simultaneously?

Tags: android, android-usb

I am developing two apps that use the same USB device, but serve different purposes.  The USB driver for both apps are the same, however, I would like it to where both apps can be running simultaneously while using the same USB device.

Unfortunately, as of right now, when using the USB device in App A, App B loses communication with the device when running in the background with App A active and receiving data.  I would like both Apps A and B to receive the same data simultaneously with one app active while the other is running in the background.

I wonder, is this even possible?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue? I'm having the same problem